# Is there a shortcut with jQuery that allows me to specify multiple attributes at once?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$target
    .attr('data-title', targetTitle)
    .attr('title', '');
```

Is there a way I can set both attr at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs)?

Comment: For data HTML5 type attribute, you should use property .data() not .attr(). In your example, you should use: $target.data('title',targetTitle).attr('title','');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set multiple values at once in jquery always use **map**

for example - case with attr()

```
       $('#greatphoto').attr({
        'data-title': targetTitle,
         'title': ''
         });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can [pass a JavaScript object](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs). Each key-value pair in the object adds or modifies an attribute.

```
$target.attr({
  'data-title': targetTitle,
  'title': ''
});
```

As documented in [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> **`.attr( attributes )`**
>
> - **`attributes`**
>
>   **Type**: Plain Object
>
>   An object of attribute-value pairs to set.

You may want to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for your `data-*` attributes.